# @Html.HiddenFor does not pass value from CheckBoxFor to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Im trying to pass from @Html.CheckBoxFor to controller but it does not pass true values. i have ViewModel containing an IList of another ViewModel which contains bool isSelected which doesnt seem to be passed. The code looks like that

```
public class PackageItemsViewModel
    {


        public IList<ItemsViewModel> items{ get; set; }
    }

 public class ItemsViewModel
    {
       [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Type { get; set; }

            public bool isSelected { get; set; }
}
```

and in View

```
  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.items.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.devices[i].Id)

                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.items[i].isSelected)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.items[i].isSelected)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: Remove `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.items[i].isSelected)` - The `DefaultmodelBinder` only binds the first input with matching names - your checkbox value is being ignored

Comment: @StephenMuecke damn man, post it as an answer so i can accept it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultModelBinder` binds only the first value it finds with a matching property. In you case your `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.items[i].isSelected)` is rendering the initial value you sent to the view, and because its before the checkbox, you will only ever bind to that initial value (your checkbox is being ignored).

Simply remove the `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.items[i].isSelected)` and the value will be correctly bound.

Note that the `CheckBoxFor()` method generate both a checkbox (with `value="true"` and a hidden input with `value="false"` so that if the checkbox is checked, both `true` and `false` are posted (but only `true` is bound) and if unchecked. only `false` is posted.